# MATLAB - Need to make a cell array from a text column file

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, text-files

I have a database from UCI Machine Learning ([Abalone Database](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data))and I need to separate the first column, which is a `character`, from the other columns, which are `double`.

The second part I already have with this code:

```
abaloneData = csvread('abalone.data',0,1);
```

I tried a lot to gatter the first part to use on KNN, but I failed every time.

Thanks.

**EDIT1:**

**read_data.m**

```
function [features, labels] = read_data()
    features = csvread('abalone.data',0,1);

    fileID = fopen('abalone.data');
    data = textscan(fileID,'%s %*[^\n]', 'Delimiter',',');
    fclose(fileID);
    labels = cell2mat(data{1});
end
```

**knn.m**

```
[features,labels] = read_data();

Mdl = fitcknn(features,labels);
```

Comment: This is done with `textscan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you've probably realized by now, is that `csvread()` only works for numeric values.  Instead you need to use `textscan()` to deal with strings / characters. Try this:

```
fileID = fopen('abalone.data');
data = textscan(fileID,'%s %*[^\n]', 'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
labels = cell2mat(data{1});
```

This will open the file and read in the first column as a string, skipping the remaining elements in each row. Finally, this data gets converted from cell to a char vector called `labels`

Comment: Your code gives me an array of char, but when I try to use the KNN, I get this error: `??? Undefined function or method 'fitcknn' for input arguments of type 'double'.`. Do you know what's the problem? I'll edit the question to add the entire code.

Comment: Your edited code works fine for me. `fitcknn()` is a function belonging to the statistics toolbox.  Are you sure you have access to this toolbox?

Comment: I am. If you want, I can print the help response.

Comment: Do I need to activate something before using?

Comment: In your matlab command line, execute `ver`.  Double check that you see `Statistics Toolbox` in the list that is returned.  You can check further with `help fitcknn` to ensure you have access to that function.

Comment: That must be it. I have the Statistics Toolbox on the list, but I get no response from `help fitcknn`. Thank you! Gonna update Matlab.

Comment: If this issue is resolved, please go ahead and accept this answer as correct.

Comment: Downloaded the last version of Matlab and it worked great! Thanks, @Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `textscan` if the number of columns is the same for each row:

```
fp=fopen('f.txt','rt')
a=textscan(fp,'%c%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f','delimiter',',')
fclose(fp)
```

the `cellarray` contains the data stored in the file.

Its size should be (1xn) where "`n`" is the number of columns of the file.

Comment: This one returns an array with all the text elements. I need only the first column.